# Identification of location of ship yard or naval base

Tags: military, naval, identification

[image]I need help in identifying the location of this ship yard or naval base.

Comment: Do you have any other information about this image? How you came across it, for instance?

Comment: I purchased the photo on ebay with many images of Wickes and Clemson class destroyers probably@ 1930. Also images of USS Chicago.

Answer (score 14):

[Mare Island Naval Shipyard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mare_Island_Naval_Shipyard)

If you want to confirm for yourself, [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mare_Island_Naval_Shipyard_in_1930.jpg) is an aerial photograph of the yard dated 1930. Going from center to center-right is the gantry visible in your image, and if you look near the end of the gantry to the right, you'll see that building with the neoclassical portico and the little tower, and right next to it a brick warehouse with an angled roof. The background matches up, too.

Bonus points: the photo also depicts USS Chicago (CA 29), launched but not yet commissioned!

Comment: Nice detective work.  One of the more interesting side stories of WWII is the competition between private yards and Navy-owned yards.  E.g. the Navy yards built Gato-class submarines at a faster rate and less cost than the privately-owned yards.  The Navy continued to build new construction ships in its own yards until the 1960s and found doing so helped it better monitor cost overruns billed by the private yards for identical ships.